# Haskell ReadFile fails for existing files

Tags: haskell, readfile, io-monad

I'm writing a function in Haskell as part of a compiler to open a file, read a set of file names from it and concatenate them into a string. The code runs fine in ghci but fails when compiled with the following:

> fact.fn: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

I am completely sure fact.fn exists and it's in the same directory as the executable.

Relevant code:

```
compile [fileName] = do  
             (ilude, contents) <- imports fileName
             let lude = "prelude.fn" : ilude
             prld <- fmap fullPrelude (mapM readFile lude) --seems to fail here, 
--but works fine in the interpreter
             let newPrld = unlines [prld, "\nend"]
             runEvalWith HappyParser.parseExpr fileName contents newPrld


imports :: String -> IO ([String], String)
imports fileName = do 
    contents <- readFile fileName
    let ls = lines contents
    let ifile = filter (isPrefixOf "import") ls {-find import string here-}
    let contentList = filter (\w -> w `notElem` ifile) ls
    let impts = mapMaybe (stripPrefix "import") ifile
    return (impts, (unlines contentList) )


fullPrelude :: [String] -> String
fullPrelude [] = ""
fullPrelude xs = unlines( map (procPrelude) xs)

procPrelude :: String -> String
procPrelude pld = unlines(init(words pld))
```

Comment: Do you run it in the same directory? The location of the executable is irrelevant: it takes the `pwd` and adds the filename to it.

Comment: In addition to Willem's comment- If you are on Windows: If on PowerShell `pwd` is predefined as an alias for `Get-Location` which returns the current location. On CMD `pwd` is not available, to get the current directory run `cd` (without any arguments).

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and I do run in the same directory. I even copied to new directory to check for permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that, in processing an import command like:

```
import fact.fn
```

you are not stripping the space from the beginning of the filename, so your program is actually trying to import the file `" fact.fn"` and not `"fact.fn"`.  You can verify that this is the case if you study the error message carefully.  If the error is:

```
*** Exception:  fact.fn: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

with two spaces instead of one between `Exception:` and `fact.fn`, then there's an extra space at the beginning of the filename.

I have absolutely no idea how you were able to run it successfully in the interpreter.

Comment: Many thanks!! Feels like a total noob job that I missed that.